# Implementation details of Firebase iOS SDK callback function

Tags: ios, callback, firebase

I am developing an iOS app. I have situation in which I use one to many type of callback. This requirement is very fulfilled by NSNotification centre or key-value observing. However, I just wanted to know which of the two is being used behind the scene in Firebase iOS sdk callbacks which are like this `(FirebaseHandle)observeAuthEventWithBlock:(void ( ^ ) ( FAuthData     *authData ))block`

This would help me improve my code a lot. Thanks

Comment: We have found that Firebase insulates us from (needing to know) the inner workings of how it's handling notifications. Do you have a situation where the internal Firebase notifications affects your code? If so, you may want to  investigate another coding direction. The code block you posted could easily be rolled into KVO or notifications.

Comment: @Jay Even I was thinking on the same question. I had the same case. I wanted to know if there was a better way of doing this than KVO or Notifications and it was then I stumbled upon this firebase and was curious to know if what they are using is better than KVO or Notifications. If you have some idea, please share. PS: I have already implemented Notifications in my code.

Comment: @kerry We don't know the inner workings but have not really needed too. The back end leverages sockets so because of that there are mostly likely both KVO and notifications involved at some point. As a side note that doesn't really address the question; with the block that is called when observing a node, you could easily update a KVO'd property or just as easily send a notification out.